# How to continue Rx2 interval if there is an error

Tags: android, rx-java2

Here is a code with network call on every period of time. If network call fails then interval stops repeating

```
   if (userManager.isLoggedIn()) {
        notificationsRefreshSubscription = Observable
                .interval(0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
                .flatMap {
                    return@flatMap service.checkForNewNotifications(
                            token = userManager.getUser().takeToken(),
                            locale = userManager.getUserLanguageCode())
                }
                .observeOn(uiScheduler)
                .subscribe({
                    listener?.onNewNotificationsReceived(it.count)
                }, {
                    // Empty
                })
    }
```

how can I continue interval repeating even on error?

With help of @akarnokd **Answer is:**

`return@flatMap service.checkForNewNotifications(
     token = userManager.getUser().takeToken(),
     locale = userManager.getUserLanguageCode())
     .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())`

all the magic was to put `.onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())` inside `.flatmap()`

Comment: Pick: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators

Comment: I can't make them work on .interval(). Any example?

Comment: You can't do `checkForNewNotifications(...).onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())`?

Comment: How does `Observable.empty()` solve the issue? Doesn't it complete the stream preventing any interval events to keep on happening?

Comment: Instead of returning observable with error it returns empty one so chain wont brake

Comment: @AntonisRadz But doesn't it terminate the stream anyway preventing the interval from continuing hence ending up in the same issue as you had before?